# Запуск android приложения по ссылке из браузера

Tags: android

Вот тут разбирали вопрос по поводу запуска приложения по ссылке в браузере. https://toster.ru/q/311198

Моя задача: есть приложение, которое по usb,wi-fi цепляется к кассе АТОЛ-30Ф и печатает чек. Нужно из вэб системы по ссылке запускать приложение, которое будет получать, например, id чека - по нему находить позиции в чеке и печатать сам чек. Приложение уже работает. Необходимо лишь вызывать его из браузера.

Вопрос №1. Приложение обязательно должно быть опубликовано в google play? делал по инструкции - приложение не найдено. Прописывал имя пакета, имя действия и тп. не помогает. Приложение для своей организации, будет запускаться из вэб системы компании, так что опубликовывать его смысла нет - и платить за это деньги - тоже.

Вопрос №2. Можно ли таким же способом обращаться не к Activity, а к службе? Смысл в том, чтобы при клике по ссылке, передавались данные службе, она отрабатывала бы все в фоне, не открывая само приложение.

Comment: Вы пробовали Deep Linking? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая ссылка называется [Deep Link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)

Если не вдаваться в дебри, то вам нужно в манифесте прописать что-то навроде:

```
 <intent-filter >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
     <data android:host="myhost" android:scheme="myapp"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

и далее в HTML прописать ссылку типа:

```
myapp://myhost
```

В этом случае, будет запущен стандартный `Intent` с `action.View`, который по схеме `myapp` запустит ваше приложение.

P.S. Надеюсь понятно, что это работает только в Android браузере :)

P.P.S. Публиковать в Play нет необходимости.

Comment: Это касается запуска activity? или службу так тоже можно запустить? Получится вызвать приложение в фоне? чтобы не вываливался на экран.

Comment: Не уверен, что `Service` так можно запустить, но попробовать можно, по крайней мере синтаксически в теге `<service>` все это можно написать

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Службу так запустить нельзя. >> Android's deep linking functionality is available to foreground activities only (ref).

Possible Solution

You could start an Activity (transparent/noHistory/excludeFromRecents/singleInstance) which calls the Service (or the desired activities).

Comment: а как передать параметр в ссылке?